# ICommand click event null exception with PushAsync

Tags: c#

I am having a little issue which I can't seem to wrap my mind about. I am using xamarin.forms to create a crossplatform application and I want to use the Icommand to bind the click event of my buttons to push a page.

This is the code behind that works

```
 public void NextPage(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new SelectionPage());
        }
```

I made a seperate viewmodel shown below:

```
 public class HomeScreenViewModel  {

    public INavigation _navigation;

   public ICommand NewPage {
        get {
            return new Command(async () => {
             await _navigation.PushAsync(new SelectionPage());
            });
        }
    }
    public HomeScreenViewModel() {
    }
    public HomeScreenViewModel(INavigation navigation) {
        _navigation = navigation;

        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button the code will give a object null exception which I can't seem to be able to fix.

Also this is the XAML binding:
`Command="{Binding NewPage}"`

I hope someone could help me solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the proper Constructor is getting called when you set the DataContext in your HomeScreen.cs and passing in the INavigation Property to be set? When you create you view Model and set the context you need to call the Constructor that accepts the INavigation Property.  Otherwise _navigation will be null when you attempt to call it.

Comment: and how do I do such thing? I currently call this in my homescreen.cs:

BindingContext = new HomeScreenViewModel();

Comment: problem has been solved

BindingContext= new HomeScreenViewModel(Navigation);

Comment: thats exactly where I was going when you set your binding context you need to make sure you call the constructor that takes the Navigation Parameter.